# jira-python create_issue jiraerror http 400 with a url of local address

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm new to jira-python. I am trying to automate a bit on jira management, blocked on creating issue for a long time, going along with the jira-python official documents.
I'm confused with the createmeta of create_issue() method. After trial and error, I'm blocked with a strange http 400 error followed by a url with a local address.

### **Environment:**

> OS, Windows 10.
>
> Spyder IDE in Anaconda(latest version with Python 3.5 installed)
>
> jira-python, 1.0.7

There are several 'projects' on the customized JIRA deployed, and I'm interested on the project-'ZXQ', in which I create an issue manually with 'Project', 'Issue Type', 'Summary', and 'Priority' required (This is my first post on stackoverflow, and I don't have permission to upload pic.).

Here are the code, error message, and createmeta in tidy manner.

### **Code:**

```
from jira import JIRA

authedjira = JIRA(server = 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082', 
            basic_auth = ('username', 'password'))

issue_dict = {
    'project': {'key': 'ZXQ'},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'}
#           'priority' : '0-Blocked'
}

new_issue = authedjira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
```

### **msg in console:**

```
runfile('.../Spyder/test/tcreateissue.py', wdir='.../Spyder/test')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-16266e46b0c1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('.../Spyder/test/tcreateissue.py', wdir='.../Spyder/test')

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File ".../Spyder/test/tcreateissue.py", line 21, in <module>
    new_issue = authedjira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 897, in create_issue
    r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 152, in post
    return self.__verb('POST', url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 145, in __verb
    raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)

  File "C:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 55, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)

JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issue details: C:\Users\ABSmi\AppData\Local\Temp\jiraerror-jjcv0rwp.tmp
```

Content in jiraerror-jjcv0rwp.tmp:

```
response headers = {'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'X-AREQUESTID': '1024x353617x1', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Sun, 31 Jul 2016 09:04:51 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'X-ASESSIONID': 'sen5dn', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'zhaoya', 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-5285313', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform'}
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"description":"Field 'description' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

### **createmeta:**

```
{
   "expand": "projects",
   


   ================================================================================================================================================
   ================================================================================================================================================
   ================================================================================================================================================



   "projects": [


      
      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================



      {
         "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/project/11001",
         "id": "11001",
         "name": "Precheck",
         "key": "PRECHECK",
         "issuetypes": [
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
               "id": "1",
               "name": "Bug",
               "description": "A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/bug.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/2",
               "id": "2",
               "name": "New Feature",
               "description": "A new feature of the product, which has yet to be developed.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/newfeature.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
               "id": "3",
               "name": "Task",
               "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/task.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/4",
               "id": "4",
               "name": "Improvement",
               "description": "An improvement or enhancement to an existing feature or task.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/improvement.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
               "id": "5",
               "name": "Sub-task",
               "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/subtask_alternate.png",
               "subtask": true
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10001",
               "id": "10001",
               "name": "\u6d4b\u8bd5",
               "description": "\u6b64\u53d1\u5e03\u7c7b\u578b\u7528\u4e8e\u5728 Jira \u4e2d\u521b\u5efa Zephyr \u6d4b\u8bd5\u3002",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/com.thed.zephyr.je/images/icons/ico_zephyr_issuetype.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10100",
               "id": "10100",
               "name": "Epic",
               "description": "Created by JIRA Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a big user story that needs to be broken down.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/epic.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10200",
               "id": "10200",
               "name": "Ticket Template(WBSGantt)",
               "description": "Ticket Template",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/template-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10201",
               "id": "10201",
               "name": "Phase",
               "description": "Project Development Phase",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/phase-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            }
         ],
         "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=11001&avatarId=10011",
            "16x16": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=11001&avatarId=10011",
            "32x32": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=11001&avatarId=10011",
            "48x48": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?pid=11001&avatarId=10011"
         }
      },



      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================



      {
         "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/project/11200",
         "id": "11200",
         "name": "\u4e8b\u4ef6\u7ba1\u7406",
         "key": "SJGL",
         "issuetypes": [
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
               "id": "5",
               "name": "Sub-task",
               "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/subtask_alternate.png",
               "subtask": true
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/2",
               "id": "2",
               "name": "New Feature",
               "description": "A new feature of the product, which has yet to be developed.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/newfeature.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
               "id": "3",
               "name": "Task",
               "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/task.png",
               "subtask": false
            }
         ],
         "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=11200&avatarId=10011",
            "16x16": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=11200&avatarId=10011",
            "32x32": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=11200&avatarId=10011",
            "48x48": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?pid=11200&avatarId=10011"
         }
      },



      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================



      {
         "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/project/10201",
         "id": "10201",
         "name": "\u4ea7\u54c1\u5185\u90e8\u4ea4\u6d41",
         "key": "CP",
         "issuetypes": [
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
               "id": "1",
               "name": "Bug",
               "description": "A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/bug.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/2",
               "id": "2",
               "name": "New Feature",
               "description": "A new feature of the product, which has yet to be developed.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/newfeature.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
               "id": "3",
               "name": "Task",
               "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/task.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/4",
               "id": "4",
               "name": "Improvement",
               "description": "An improvement or enhancement to an existing feature or task.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/improvement.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
               "id": "5",
               "name": "Sub-task",
               "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/subtask_alternate.png",
               "subtask": true
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10001",
               "id": "10001",
               "name": "\u6d4b\u8bd5",
               "description": "\u6b64\u53d1\u5e03\u7c7b\u578b\u7528\u4e8e\u5728 Jira \u4e2d\u521b\u5efa Zephyr \u6d4b\u8bd5\u3002",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/com.thed.zephyr.je/images/icons/ico_zephyr_issuetype.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10100",
               "id": "10100",
               "name": "Epic",
               "description": "Created by JIRA Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a big user story that needs to be broken down.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/epic.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10200",
               "id": "10200",
               "name": "Ticket Template(WBSGantt)",
               "description": "Ticket Template",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/template-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10201",
               "id": "10201",
               "name": "Phase",
               "description": "Project Development Phase",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/phase-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            }
         ],
         "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10201&avatarId=10011",
            "16x16": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10201&avatarId=10011",
            "32x32": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10201&avatarId=10011",
            "48x48": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?pid=10201&avatarId=10011"
         }
      },



      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================



      {
         "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/project/11009",
         "id": "11009",
         "name": "\u4ea7\u54c1\u8bbe\u8ba1\u9700\u6c42",
         "key": "PD",
         "issuetypes": [
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
               "id": "1",
               "name": "Bug",
               "description": "A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/bug.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/2",
               "id": "2",
               "name": "New Feature",
               "description": "A new feature of the product, which has yet to be developed.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/newfeature.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
               "id": "3",
               "name": "Task",
               "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/task.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/4",
               "id": "4",
               "name": "Improvement",
               "description": "An improvement or enhancement to an existing feature or task.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/improvement.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
               "id": "5",
               "name": "Sub-task",
               "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/subtask_alternate.png",
               "subtask": true
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10001",
               "id": "10001",
               "name": "\u6d4b\u8bd5",
               "description": "\u6b64\u53d1\u5e03\u7c7b\u578b\u7528\u4e8e\u5728 Jira \u4e2d\u521b\u5efa Zephyr \u6d4b\u8bd5\u3002",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/com.thed.zephyr.je/images/icons/ico_zephyr_issuetype.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10100",
               "id": "10100",
               "name": "Epic",
               "description": "Created by JIRA Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a big user story that needs to be broken down.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/epic.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10200",
               "id": "10200",
               "name": "Ticket Template(WBSGantt)",
               "description": "Ticket Template",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/template-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10201",
               "id": "10201",
               "name": "Phase",
               "description": "Project Development Phase",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/phase-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            }
         ],
         "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=11009&avatarId=10011",
            "16x16": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=11009&avatarId=10011",
            "32x32": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=11009&avatarId=10011",
            "48x48": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?pid=11009&avatarId=10011"
         }
      },



      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================
      ================================================================================================



      {
         "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/project/10005",
         "id": "10005",
         "name": "\u7f3a\u9677\u7ba1\u7406\u5e73\u53f0",
         "key": "ZXQ",
         "issuetypes": [
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
               "id": "1",
               "name": "Bug",
               "description": "A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/bug.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/2",
               "id": "2",
               "name": "New Feature",
               "description": "A new feature of the product, which has yet to be developed.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/newfeature.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
               "id": "3",
               "name": "Task",
               "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/task.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/4",
               "id": "4",
               "name": "Improvement",
               "description": "An improvement or enhancement to an existing feature or task.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/improvement.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
               "id": "5",
               "name": "Sub-task",
               "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/subtask_alternate.png",
               "subtask": true
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10001",
               "id": "10001",
               "name": "\u6d4b\u8bd5",
               "description": "\u6b64\u53d1\u5e03\u7c7b\u578b\u7528\u4e8e\u5728 Jira \u4e2d\u521b\u5efa Zephyr \u6d4b\u8bd5\u3002",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/com.thed.zephyr.je/images/icons/ico_zephyr_issuetype.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10100",
               "id": "10100",
               "name": "Epic",
               "description": "Created by JIRA Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a big user story that needs to be broken down.",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/images/icons/issuetypes/epic.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10200",
               "id": "10200",
               "name": "Ticket Template(WBSGantt)",
               "description": "Ticket Template",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/template-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            },
            {
               "self": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/rest/api/2/issuetype/10201",
               "id": "10201",
               "name": "Phase",
               "description": "Project Development Phase",
               "iconUrl": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/download/resources/jp.ricksoft.plugins.wbsgantt-for-jira:wbsgantt-resources/images/phase-icon.png",
               "subtask": false
            }
         ],
         "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10005&avatarId=10011",
            "16x16": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10005&avatarId=10011",
            "32x32": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10005&avatarId=10011",
            "48x48": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:48082/secure/projectavatar?pid=10005&avatarId=10011"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: 400 is only the status code (bad request), the body of the response should contain more details about what went wrong. I guess that's also what this part of your error message refers to: "details: C:\Users\ABSmi\AppData\Local\Temp\jiraerror-jjcv0rwp.tmp". So what's in that file?

Comment: Thanks for help. Contents in the .tmp file is added in the question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error detail message is:

```
Field 'description' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
```

If you go to the *Project Settings* of your project in JIRA and click on *Screens* then you can check the *Screen Scheme* that is associated with your project. The screen scheme lists which screen is used for each issue operation (create, edit, view). Your *Create Screen* does not contain the *description* field, but you do try to set it in the body of your create request. That's why you get the 400 error.

You have a few options:

- Don't specify the description field in your request body
- Update your *Create Screen* to show the *description* field

More information about how project screens, schemes etc. relate to each other is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/project-screens-schemes-and-fields-802592517.html).
More information about how to configure screens is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/defining-a-screen-802592587.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't expect to get answer from the .tmp file since I considered it to be unreadable. This problem is solved now.


But I get a problem further to be solved. How can I get the fields and their corresponding values as I'm not the administrator of the JIRA deployed?

Comment: (Ah! BTW, how can I begin a new line in comment in StackOverflow?!)

Comment: TEST to begin  <br/>

a new line

Comment: You cannot add newlines in comments (unfortunately). As for your other question: you can use the createmeta REST resource to figure out which fields you can set when you create issues. Documentation is available here: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getCreateIssueMeta . Possibly you'll have to contact your JIRA admin to help you out if you don't have a user with sufficient permissions. If you have other questions best to post them separately instead of in comments.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into the reference you provide, and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the search query, even though it was returning a field was not correct.
The issue was the personal access token had expired and I had to remake t again and update it

options = {'server':'http://jira.company.com', 'verify':False}
jira = JIRA(options, token_auth='TOKEN_SECRET_KEY')

I am using the Jira library and python 3.6

Answer (score -1):

don't have permissions on jira project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).